# SSH keys not considered while using "eval" in shell

Tags: git, shell, ssh, eval

I am trying to do a git clone in a shell script where the repo URL is evaluated dynamically.
I have tried below in my script:

`git clone 'git_repo_url'` works fine

`x='git_repo_url'; git clone $x` works fine

I am using eval to dynamically create the repo URL, and `echo $(eval xyz)` gives the exact same repo URL as above i.e. `'git_repo_url'`

- However `git clone $(eval xyz)` fails with `Permission denied (publickey)` error.
- Also, `x=$(eval xyz)` and `git clone $x` also fails `Permission denied (publickey)` error.

My SSH keys are configured in the default location ~/.ssh and also have ~/.ssh/config in place. I am unable to figure out what is going wrong here.

This is what I see with `(set -x; git clone $(eval xyz))`

```
git clone ''\''git_repo_url'\'''
```

So those quotes and slashes are causing the issue, but not sure why.

**Why I am using eval**

1. The "git_repo_url" for various projects are exported as environment variables.
   The format of the environment variable is as follows:

   `project_<project_name>_git='git_repo_url'`
2. `<project_name>` is passed as the first input parameter to the shell script that does the git clone
3. So to form the environment variable, I am using eval:

   `$(eval echo \$\{project_$1_git\})`

Comment: Try `(set -x; git clone $(eval xyz))` and include what that shows you..

Comment: Shell `eval` constructs are tricky and, for beginners, usually best avoided, but remember that `eval` takes a string argument and runs it through the shell's evaluation system as if it had been typed in as a command. This means that if someone hands you `rm -rf $HOME` and you "eval" that, you've just removed your entire account.

Comment: If `eval xyz` produces the single quotes, that's the problem. Quotes from an expansion are *not* subject to quote removal like the quotes you type at the command line.

Comment: Yes, the issue is expansion vs command execution. So while `echo $(eval xyz)` removes quotes, `$(eval xyz)` retains it.

Comment: My suggestion would be to modify `xyz` so it outputs the URL without any quotes at all. This worked for me: `git clone $(eval 'echo https://github.com/me/repo.git')` so if you construct `xyz` so that its output is plainly `git_repo_url` things should work.

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, `eval` is probably the wrong solution to begin with.

Comment: do you have a higher reason to use `eval` ? wouldn't `x=$(xyz); git clone $x` work just the same in your case ? (also : what is in `xyz` ?)

Comment: I have added the reason for using eval in the question. As of now I could not find any other better way of doing it.

Comment: It works fine now. I simply replaced single quotes with double, in the environment variable ie,  project_<project_name>_git="git_repo_url"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use eval to construct an echo of the value you want using the arbitrary-command-execution hammer, use bash's expansion-indirection option, it's simple, safe, efficient, ...:

```
urlname=project_${project_name}_git
git clone ${!urlname}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works. I did try this earlier, but was missing the expansion-indirection parameter (!) and hence it wasn't working.